# Powershell - use CSV to create multiple text files

Tags: powershell, loops, csv

I am trying to create a PS script that autogenerates txt files using a CSV file as an input.

The CSV file contains data such as this:

| Category | Product | Priced |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bike | Red bike | Yes |
| Bike | Blue bike | Yes |
| Bike | Black bike | No |
| Car | Red car | No |
| Car | Blue car | Yes |

The script should get a CSV as an input and generate 2 txt files (because we have 2 categories):

Example:

**txt file 1: Bike.txt**

```text
Red bike - Yes
Blue bike - Yes
Black bike - No
```

I tried using this code, but it does not act the way I want it to:

```
$csv = Import-CSV -Path path.csv -Delimiter ";"

foreach($record in $csv){

    $cat_array += $record.Category

    foreach($Product in $cat_array){
        .....
    }
}
```

I think I am handling the logic wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```sh
# Group CSV data by column Category and loop over groups
Import-CSV -Path path.csv -Delimiter ";" | Group-Object Category | ForEach-Object {

    # Create a text file from the current group
    $fileName = "$($_.Name).txt"
    Set-Content $fileName -Value "$($_.Name) file contains:"

    # Loop over the rows of the CSV and add the data to the txt file
    $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
        # Format one line of the current text file
        ($_.Product, $_.Priced) -join ' - '
    } | Add-Content $fileName
}
```

**Output:**

Bike.txt

```text
Red bike - Yes
Blue bike - Yes
Black bike - No
```

Car.txt

```text
Red car - No
Blue car - Yes
```

**Detailed explanation:**

The `Group-Object` command groups data by specified criteria, in this case the value of property (column) `Category`. To better understand how it works, it helps to remove the `ForEach-Object` command:

```
Import-CSV -Path path.csv -Delimiter ";" | Group-Object Category
```

This outputs:

```text
Count Name Group
----- ---- -----
    3 Bike {@{Category=Bike; Product=Red bike; Priced=Yes}, @{Category=Bike; Product=Blue bike; Priced=Yes}, @{Category=Bike;…
    2 Car  {@{Category=Car; Product=Red car; Priced=No}, @{Category=Car; Product=Blue car; Priced=Yes}}
```

So for each group (`Bike`, `Car`), it outputs one object, which has the properties `Count` (number of grouped objects), `Name` (value of property by which it groups) and `Group` (an array of grouped objects).

So when iterating over the output of `Group-Object`, the `ForEach-Object` script block gets called one time per group. At this level the file will be created.

We then iterate over the elements of the `Group` array, which contains the rows of the CSV for the current category, to create the lines of the file, using the `-join` operator to format each line. This ends up in the file because it is *implicit* output, piped to the next command.

Finally output the file by piping to `Set-Content`. If necessary, use the `-Encoding` parameter to specify a non-default encoding (PS 5.x defaults to ANSI, while PS 7.x defaults to UTF-8).

Comment: What if I want to add a some text to the txt, such as: 
Bike fike contains:

Red bike - Yes
Blue bike - Yes
Black bike - No.

How would this be done in the code?

Comment: @uba2012 I've edited the code to show how you can insert a line at the top of the file using `Set-Content` and then use `Add-Content` to append the data from the CSV.

Comment: how do i output the group into a string variable for further manipulation? 

I have tried Out-String instead of add-content, but i cannot seem to manipulate it.

Comment: @uba2012 `$groupStr = $_.Group | ForEach-Object {($_.Product, $_.Priced) -join ' - '} | Out-String`